# Charlock_holmes installation error, Windows 11

Tags: ruby, windows, dependencies, rubygems

I am trying to install the Charlock_holmes dependency but I keep getting this error:

```
$ gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions with: '--with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/ext/charlock_holmes
C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb --with-icui18nlib\=icuin --with-icudatalib\=icudt
checking for -licuin... no


***************************************************************************************
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-icu-dir
        --without-icu-dir
        --with-icu-include
        --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
        --with-icu-lib
        --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
        --with-icu-i18n-dir
        --without-icu-i18n-dir
        --with-icu-i18n-include
        --without-icu-i18n-include=${icu-i18n-dir}/include
        --with-icu-i18n-lib
        --without-icu-i18n-lib=${icu-i18n-dir}/lib
        --with-icu-i18n-config
        --without-icu-i18n-config
etc
```

I spent a good couple of hours looking for a solution but with no luck.

I already tried:

- Installing icu4c from https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-71-1 and put the path in "--with-icu-lib"
- using:

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-icu icu-devel icu
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt
```

Comment: And what's the logged error in `mkmf.log`? I've never used ruby installer/ridk or windows in general to work with ruby, even less knowing how WSL works, but I wonder if really the gem is compatible with your system.

Comment: @AlterLagos
package configuration for icu-i18n is not found //

package configuration for icu-io is not found //

package configuration for icu-uc is not found //

have_library: checking for -licuin... -------------------- no

Answer (score 1):

These worked for me

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-icu icu-devel icu
ridk enable
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt
```

Edit:

Along the way I also installed this

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-ruby-pkg-config
```